# Dynamically resize text in a textarea while typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

To display a custom font I would like a textarea where users can type text with this custom font. When you type one word the font-size is for instance 150px and as you type more, it should reduce the font-size with a set minimum. Removing text should enlarge the font-size again.
I've tried this with a simple script, see below, reducing text size by a certain amount after typing a certain amount of characters but it's hard to find the right ratio. Typing the first few words does not reduce the font-size enough and with more text it reduces the font-size too much.

```
var textarea = $('#textarea');
textarea.bind('change input', function() {
    if (this.value.length % 5 == 0) {
        textarea.animate({'font-size': '-=5px'});
    }
});
```

This is a very simple example to test if this is possible, it only reduces the size.

I've seen many stackoverflow questions and js libraries (like [FlowType](https://github.com/simplefocus/FlowType.JS) and [TextFill](https://github.com/jquery-textfill/jquery-textfill)) to resize the textarea or divs to fit the text, but I have not found anything about dynamically resizing text within a textarea as you type.

Any suggestions?

Comment: share what you have tried.

Comment: Can you please post the code here or in jsFiddle/jsBin ?

Comment: I've added the simple text script and links to 2 js libraries I tried to make it work on a textarea but did not succeed.

Answer (score 0):

try This 
Script

```
$(function(){

        var textarea = $('#box');
        textarea.bind('change input', function() {
            textarea.css({'font-size':(textarea.css('font-size').replace('px','')-3)});

            });
        });
```

Html

```
<input type="text" style="width:15px" id="box" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but the question is how to fit the text nicely in a textarea. Changing the font-size actually works with my code example.